# How to break the loop after 5 attempts?

Tags: java

```
//File name: SmallIO.java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmallIO{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        String a = "";   // initialise to empty string

        while (true){
            //an infinite loop, use Ctrl-C (from command prompt) to quit

            System.out.println("Enter a line:");

            a = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Your line: " + a);

            System.out.println();
        }//end of while

    }//end of main

}//end of class
```

Comment: If you need to count use a `for` loop, not a `while`.

Comment: Also, you may want to break the loop on some other condition, I guess. Because as it stands you're repeatedly asking for a value and ignoring what is input.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways, the simplest one would be to use an actual for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++) {....}
```

This is the same as:

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= 5) {.... i++; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To break a loop(any loop), you use the `break` statement.

To break a loop after 5 iterations, you use a counter

This is one of the way to use a counter in combination with `break`

```java
int counter = 0;
while(true) {
    counter++;
    if (counter == 5) break;
}
```